# error al crear proyecto de react usando npx

Tags: reactjs, npm, terminal, macos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estoy aprendiendo a usar react js, pero tengo problemas al intentar hacer correr el npm en la terminal en mi mac, pongo el codigo "npm install -g create-react-app" y me sale un error de permisos, pero la verdad no entiendo como resolver eso, sera que alguien me puede dar una mano por favor

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para lo mismo. Saludos.

Comment: Pon eso como texto, es imposible leer una imagen tan pequeña (y no podemos copiar y pegar en la respuesta para explicar nada. Deberías leerte el [tour] de bienvenida para aprender a realizar buenas preguntas que den ganas de responder :)

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema.. trate de crearlo con el admin root y el error es el mismo.. Me dice que los permisos son denegados.. alguna recomendación..?

Answer (score 1):

Hasta donde tengo entendido, los `npm install -g` se utilizan exclusivamente para librerías o frameworks, para el uso de algún framework, esto es ajeno al uso de un proyecto.

Para los proyectos, vas en alguna carpeta y ejecutas:

```
npx create-react-app NombreDeMiProyecto
```

En caso te salte un error de permisos, se soluciona ejecutando el comando

```
sudo su
```

Con esto estás como root y procedes a ejecutar nuevamente:

```
npx create-react-app NombreDeMiProyecto
```